# How to extract objects from json string?

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON string and I want to extract objects from it. The problem is that simplejson.loads is throwing some error. Can you tell me how to extract objects?

```
u'[u\'{"opt_id":2949,"answer":"true"}\', u\'{"opt_id":2950,"answer":"false"}\', u\'{"opt_id":2951,"answer":"false"}\']'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a JSON string; you have a string representing a Python list object containing JSON strings instead.

The following works:

```
import json
import ast

for json_string in ast.literal_eval(inputstring):
    print json.loads(json_string)
```

Demo:

```
>>> import json
>>> import ast
>>> inputstring = u'[u\'{"opt_id":2949,"answer":"true"}\', u\'{"opt_id":2950,"answer":"false"}\', u\'{"opt_id":2951,"answer":"false"}\']'
>>> for json_string in ast.literal_eval(inputstring):
...     print json.loads(json_string)
... 
{u'answer': u'true', u'opt_id': 2949}
{u'answer': u'false', u'opt_id': 2950}
{u'answer': u'false', u'opt_id': 2951}
```

You probably need to find out *why* you got that string and not a proper JSON value, which would look like:

```
'[{"answer": "true", "opt_id": 2949}, {"answer": "false", "opt_id": 2950}, {"answer": "false", "opt_id": 2951}]'
```

instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Lot of downvotes on my question though, very strict community here I suppose :3

Comment: You did not include an error message, or details as to where the object came from. I didn't vote on your question, but that'd have helped your case.